# Google Buzz API OAuth Problem - Using Zend_OAuth (PHP)

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth, buzz

I have successfully gotten an access_token, so it's not a problem with the 3-legged process.

The problem starts when I try to add a new post/activity using the Buzz API...

Here is my request:

```
POST /buzz/v1/activities/@me/@self?alt=json HTTP/1.1 
Host: www.googleapis.com 
Connection: close 
Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate 
User-Agent: Zend_Http_Client 
Content-Type: application/json 
Authorization: OAuth 
realm="",oauth_consumer_key="example.com",oauth_nonce="ce29b04ce6648fbb92efc8f 08c1c0091",oauth_signature_method="HMAC- 
SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1277934794",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="1%2FcBz o5ckGvCAm3wLWh1SDH3xQNoW-- 
yek1NVfUa1Qqns",oauth_signature="CUezSiMbvxyN1BTeb3uROlIx8gA%3D" 
Content-Length: 86 
{"data":{"object":{"type":"note","content":"posting on Buzz"}}}
```

Here is the response:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"message":"Unknown authorization header","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Unknown authorization header"}}
```

And here is my base string (the string that the signature gets generated from):

```
POST&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fbuzz%2Fv1%2Factivities%2F%40me 
%2F%40self&oauth_consumer_key%3Dexample.com%26oauth_nonce 
%3D50acc6b7ac48304ae9301134d6988cdb%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC- 
SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1278065599%26oauth_token 
%3D1%252FcBzo5ckGvCAm3wLWh1SDH3xQNoW--yek1NVfUa1Qqns%26oauth_version 
%3D1.0
```

I've even tried this other base string (with the alt=json added in):

```
POST&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fbuzz%2Fv1%2Factivities%2F%40me
  %2F%40self%3Falt%3Djson&oauth_consumer_key%3Dexample.com%26oauth_nonce
  %3Dee8704244623bbcc860bf77bfcadeacc%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-
  SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1278069221%26oauth_token
  %3D1%252FcBzo5ckGvCAm3wLWh1SDH3xQNoW--yek1NVfUa1Qqns%26oauth_version
  %3D1.0
```

I have tried pretty much everything to get this working - not sure why it always says 'Unknown authorization header'... the header looks fine when compared to other ones that work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

which endpoint did you use to authorize request token?

[developer's guide](http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/v1/using_rest.html#authentication):

> Important: Part of the OAuth process
>   requires that you direct the user to
>   the Google Authorization service to
>   approve access for your application.
>   Google Buzz requires that you use a
>   different Authorization service
>   endpoint, located at
>   https://www.google.com/buzz/api/auth/OAuthAuthorizeToken.com/buzz/api/auth/OAuthAuthorizeToken.

Comment: Yeah, I am using the correct endpoint.

Sorry for the delayed response - been abroad. :)

Comment: actually, MY answer was delayed.. :) i just got into "buzz+oauth" business today and was searching for solution to some of my problems in the first place.. painful debugging experience. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use GET or POST method (depending what request you use). By default Zend uses header-method.

$client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::GET);

Comment: Yeah, I've already tried both GET and POST via the setMethod.